# Matlab get amount of clipping

Tags: matlab, clipping

Hi I am trying to measure the amount of clipped Samples in audio files with matlab. That means i want to get the number of all Samples that are at the Fullscale Value (at min and max). But it should just count them when there are at least two following samples at this Value.

My code so far:

```
for i = 1 :20 
    fileName = ['Elektro',num2str(i) '.wav'];
    unclipped = audioread(fileName);
    summeMax = sum(1 ==unclipped); 
    summeMin = sum(-1==unclipped);  
    summe = summeMin +summeMax;
    str=sprintf('%d ',summe);
    disp(str);
end
```

As you see its counting every sample and I would need a loop and if statements to detect if there are more than one sample at the fullscale Value.

I tried this it with a loop from `j = 1 : length(unclipped)` but it takes to long with this Method.

Anyone have suggestions how i could do this?

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534983/matlab-get-number-of-fullscale-values) to a previous question of yours, you can find all samples at which the maximum is reached by

```
maxReached = max(unclipped(:))==unclipped;
```

To remove all places where the maximum is reached for only one sample, you can use a morphological opening with the structuring element `[1,1]`:

```
clippedSamples = imopen(maxReached, [1 1]);
```

The number of clipped samples is now

```
sum(clippedSamples);
```

Of course you'll have to do the same with those samples where the minimum is reached.

Comment: ok thanks, i tried it but get everywhere the same outputs i am getting without imopen. and there are lots of outputs with 1 as result what should be impossible

Comment: I can't reproduce that. E.g. `imopen([0 1 1 0 0 1 0],[1 1])` does work and removes the single `1`. Can you maybe show a small example of the data, where it doesn't work?

Comment: i dont really know what you want to see ? 

but the thing is i tried it out how imopen works but even with [ 1 1 1 ] i get the same results
could it be that the values before imopen are saved in another format ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.. With `[ 1 1 1 ]` as input, the result should be 3, or not? `imopen` doesn't change `[1 1 1]`, as it has more than one `1`. You could e.g. add a simple example with maybe 10 vector entries and tell us what the expected result of that should be.

Comment: No sorry i meant i used imopen(max reached, [ 1 1 1] ) and nothing changed

Comment: i tried your solution with a normal vektor and it works like i want to but it dont work in my program
example : [0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
i want : [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]